# Probability function of random variable as function of another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose I had a random variable $\lambda$ with a probability density function of the form $$p_{\lambda}(x) = \cases{r(x), x \in [0, 1]\\ 0, x\notin [0, 1]}.$$

How do I find the probability function $p_{\eta}$ of the variable $\eta = \lambda^2$? Or any other $\eta(\lambda)$ for that matter?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a continuous random variable, then two main methods are in general use: Look in your text for the CDF method, which begins $F_\eta(x) = P(\eta \le x) = P(\lambda \le \sqrt{x}) = \dots.$ Then take the derivative of $F_\eta$ to get the PDF $p_\eta.$ Another method called the PDF method works for increasing fundtions. Notice (1) the support of $\eta$ is the same as of $\lambda,$ (2) squaring is increasing fcn on [0,1].

Comment: ${\mathrm{r}\left(\,\sqrt{ \eta }\,\,\right) \over 2\sqrt{\, \eta\, }}$ when $\eta \in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. You must take care of @BruceET advise about "increasing functions".

Answer (score 1):

For a random variable $X$ to have a density $p$ means that for all bounded measurable function $\phi$, $$E[\phi(X)] = \int \phi(x) p(x) dx.$$ In your case, $$E[\phi(\eta)] = E[\phi(\lambda^{2})] = \int_{0}^{1} \phi(x^{2}) r(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} \phi(x) r(\sqrt{x}) \frac{1}{2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}.$$
Therefore the density of $\eta$ is $$x \mapsto \frac{1}{2} \frac{r(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Comment: This is what I was calling the PDF method in my previous Comment.